# PHP - strftime (minutes and seconds ignored)?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, time

I tried to save time in format YYYY-mm-dd 23:59:59 to mysql database column with datetime. I don't understand why minutes and seconds are ignored always 00 ? Thank you very much for help.

PHP:

```
$time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', time());
```

Output:

```
2014-07-16 11:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple use:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

or even better use mysql `NOW()` function

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain me why this function strftime doesn't work for me ? Thank you

Comment: `php> echo strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', time()) → 2014-07-16 09:i:1405498980` is just because strftime does not understand `%i` and `%s` params as you expected (they should be `%M:%S`.)

Comment: Siemka a bedzie dzialalo kiedy zmienie v kolumnie time na timestamp i default zmienie na current_timestamp. Bedzie to dzialo bez sql INSERTU  tej value ? Jestem z czech

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify timezone as follows.

`date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
echo $date;`

The time would go by your server time. An easy workaround for this is to manually set the timezone by using date_default_timezone_set before the date() or time() functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql function

```
now()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
$time = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time());
```

from the documentation

`%S Two digit representation of the second
%M Two digit representation of the minute 00 through 59`

Also, what PHP version are you using? `%i:%s` should not be 00:00